# Handling very fast button click on Android

Tags: android

I have a "+" and "-" button that will increase/decrease the quantity  of an item.

I need to send a network request (hitting webservice) everytime the quantity is changed.

The problem is, the User probably will "spam" the "+" and "-" button. For example, they might pressed it 3 times in a second.

In regard of this case, I would like to wait a second, and then send the network request based on the last quantity. This is to reduce the number of requests i need to do (from 3 requests to just 1 request, in this case).

What is the recommended way to do this?

Can I solve this problem by using `postDelayed` in my `OnClick`?

Comment: Why do i got downvotes? :(

Comment: This sounds like a UI/UX issue, they are probably spamming the button because they don't see a response or spinner. Instead you could disable the button and show a  spinner while you are waiting for the response to complete.

Comment: @cyroxis yes I agree, the problem is I only have little control of UI/UX on this project, so i must implement what they designed

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try something like this

```
private long lastClick;

void onClick(View view) {
    lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClick >= 1000) {
                makeNetworkRequest();
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

This code will skip first requests and run only last request after 1 second pause

Comment: You could do the same thing without the post-delayed just move the `run` code directly into the `onClick` method.

Comment: But you will send new request for each button click, no?

Comment: Thanks for helping! It seems your code will not run on the first click. So the user will need to click 2 times to validate the if condition. I'm still trying to find some workaround

Comment: I changed System.currentTimeMillis() to SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() and your code is working, but it send the network requests as many as the button is clicked. I think we cant use postDelayed in this case.

Comment: I have no idea, another way you can try is using new Thread(Runnable).start(). Put in your Runnable Thread.sleep(1000) and try again. Hope it helps.

Comment: Did you replace System.currentTimeMillis() on SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() in both places?

Answer (score 0):

As an update to Ivan's answer and fixed two issues:

- The postDelayed is not needed for your logic and adds and extra 1 second delay
- Move the update to lastClick into the loop we only want it to update when we actually trigger a network call.

Example

```
private long lastClick;

void onClick(View view) {
    // Check if network call has been made in last second
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClick >= 1000) {
        // Mark time of network call    
        lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
        makeNetworkRequest();
    }
}
```